# Using file_exists per query (up to dozens per user per load)

Tags: php, performance, file

I'm creating a MySQL cache system that caches slow queries into a txt file for a predetermined time. I'm naming the txt files based on the md5 hash of the query and I'm wondering if it's too demanding for the server to check if the file exists on each query (there could be dozens of queries each page load)?

Would it be less demanding getting all txt files in the folder on pageload to memory and use that to determine if the file exists?

Comment: You should use redis or memcache for this

Comment: I'm creating this for servers that doesn't have memcache enabled.